# Mysqli fetch_assoc gives error: expects parameter mysqli_result, integer given

Tags: php, mysqli

I am wondering what's wrong with this.

First of all, it showed an error like 
**mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, integer given**.

The error shows in line `while ($prof_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($profRow)) {`

The following code below:

```
$profInfo = "SELECT * FROM register_user
                    WHERE emailAddress = '". $_SESSION['user_info']['firstName'] ."'";

    $profileInformation = mysqli_query($mysqli, $profInfo) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $profRow = mysqli_num_rows($profileInformation);

    while ($prof_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($profRow)) {
        $profFirstName = htmlspecialchars($prof_info["firstName"]);
        $profLastName = htmlspecialchars($prof_info["lastName"]);
        $profMail = htmlspecialchars($prof_info["emailAddress"]);
        $profAdd = htmlspecialchars($prof_info["mainAddress"]);
        $profCountry = htmlspecialchars($allRow["registerCountry"]);
        $profCity = htmlspecialchars($allRow["registerCity"]);
        $profZip = htmlspecialchars($allRow["postalCode"]);

        $profPostalCode = mysqli_escape_string($profZip);

        echo "<li> Name : </li>";
        echo "<span class=\"infoProfile\"> <p> $profFirstName $profLastName </p> </span>";
        echo "<li> Email : </li>";
        echo "<span class=\"infoProfile\"> <p> $profMail </p> </span>";
        echo "<li> Main Address : </li>";
        echo "<span class=\"infoProfile\"> <p> $profAdd </p> </span>";
        echo "<li> Country : </li>";
        echo "<span class=\"infoProfile\"> <p> $profCountry </p> </span>";
        echo "<li> City : </li>";
        echo "<span class=\"infoProfile\"> <p> $profCity </p> </span>";
        echo "<li> Postal Code : </li>";
        echo "<span class=\"infoProfile\"> <p> $profPostalCode </p> </span>";
        echo "<p class=\"profileLogout\"> <a href=\"logout\"> LOGOUT </a> </p>";
    }

    mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I know I'll get many downvotes for this because of the title I guess as I don't know what to put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass `$profileInformation` into `mysqli_fetch_assoc`:

```
while ($prof_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($profileInformation)) {
    ...
}
```

`mysqli_query($mysqli, $profInfo)` return `mysql_result` object, whuch is to be passed further into `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

Instead you are trying to pass an integer, which is returned by `mysqli_num_rows`.

Comment: Ohhh that's the one. Wrong value. :/ Anyway I can say it works, but it doesn't show anything on the webpage? What's wrong with this?

Comment: @Anthosiast Well, if nothing is returned and there's no error, then MySQL probably returned an empty result

Comment: but i tried the query in phpmyadmin, it works very well there.

Comment: @Anthosiast maybe `$_SESSION['user_info']['firstName']` is empty or some other value than the one you're running in phpMyAdmin

Comment: I guess so, `WHERE emailAddress = '". $_SESSION['user_info']['firstName'] ."'` should be fine right? If you can explain, how to find out the error as I already started the session on the top of the page.

Comment: `echo $_SESSION['user_info']['firstName']` and see if it's the same value you send to phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

Use `$profileInformation`  resource variable to fetch

```
    $profInfo = "SELECT * FROM register_user
                        WHERE emailAddress = '". $_SESSION['user_info']['firstName'] ."'";

        $profileInformation = mysqli_query($mysqli, $profInfo) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); // This is actual mysql result and which consist of resource Id
        $profRow = mysqli_num_rows($profileInformation);

        while ($prof_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($profileInformation )) {
//We have to pass resource id to `mysqli_fetch` 
            $profFirstName = htmlspecialchars($prof_info["firstName"]);
            $profLastName = htmlspecialchars($prof_info["lastName"]);
            $profMail = htmlspecialchars($prof_info["emailAddress"]);
            $profAdd = htmlspecialchars($prof_info["mainAddress"]);
            $profCountry = htmlspecialchars($allRow["registerCountry"]);
            $profCity = htmlspecialchars($allRow["registerCity"]);
            $profZip = htmlspecialchars($allRow["postalCode"]);

            $profPostalCode = mysqli_escape_string($profZip);

            echo "<li> Name : </li>";
            echo "<span class=\"infoProfile\"> <p> $profFirstName $profLastName </p> </span>";
            echo "<li> Email : </li>";
            echo "<span class=\"infoProfile\"> <p> $profMail </p> </span>";
            echo "<li> Main Address : </li>";
            echo "<span class=\"infoProfile\"> <p> $profAdd </p> </span>";
            echo "<li> Country : </li>";
            echo "<span class=\"infoProfile\"> <p> $profCountry </p> </span>";
            echo "<li> City : </li>";
            echo "<span class=\"infoProfile\"> <p> $profCity </p> </span>";
            echo "<li> Postal Code : </li>";
            echo "<span class=\"infoProfile\"> <p> $profPostalCode </p> </span>";
            echo "<p class=\"profileLogout\"> <a href=\"logout\"> LOGOUT </a> </p>";
        }

        mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Comment: thank you for this, i put wrong variable. And now it doesn't want to show anything on the webpage. I tried the query in phpmyadmin, it works very well there. Any ideas?